# log4j: different use of stdout file/console when in production/development

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In our company we have a log4j configuration as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CATALINA, stdout

# Used only for development.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# Define all the appenders
# configurazione catalina con meteodo di rotazione in base alla size
log4j.appender.CATALINA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CATALINA.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.CATALINA.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n




# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.c3p0=DEBUG
```

Our stdout stream goes in console when we are developing AND in a rotating file appender.

Since we manually package our files for release in production we manually comment those 3 lines and the stdout part of the first line. **EVERY TIME**

```
# Used only for development.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Forgetting in doing so means that we will have an stdout file that will contain the same info of the CATALINA rolling file appender, but will not roll, so will grow indefinitely till saturating disk space and being useless at the same time.

Is there a way to have a log4j configuration that we don't have to change everytime?

Comment: Sure is. Adapt your process to automate such things; for example by **generating** the log4 config files; depending on the build target. I know, this is not really helpful, but how exactly do you expect us to fix your build system; given the fact that we don't know anything about it?

Comment: Well, you're right it's not very helpful but the fact is that we don't have a build system.
We build it manually and package it manually every time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one answer that makes sense given your comment about not using a build system: start pulling together one **now**. If you are serious about *professional* software development, then you ought to use *professional* processes.

What you are basically saying is: "we are not doing the mandatory things; and ouch, that hurts, please make the pain go away".

Sorry, but the simple answer to that is: the **only** alternative to manual processing .. is **automation. So built that, or live with the consequences of not doing so.

Of course, you can't do such things over night, but heck: the rest of the world is talking about "continuous build" probably for 10+ years, and about "continuous delivery", aka DevOps for 3+ years. And you folks don't have a built system?!

This is not meant to be rude, but it seems that your software processes are from the last millennium; so instead of worrying about how to cure this one *symptom* ... you better step back and do a full diagnosis of your complete development chain. And then you start fixing it. You will probably uncover a lot of other small problems; and the sooner you start, the sooner you will be able to pocket in huge gains in efficiency.

And you know, I think there were companies out there that had successful products, that died at some point - because sooner or later, such manual processes lead to terrible mistakes, bugs, costumer situations, ...

Comment: Oh, it's not rude at all because it's something I (and not only me) know from a lot of time.
But as you said there has to be a full intention of doing so and in distributing the resources to do so..
Usually we are only asked to produce new features. And it's sad, I know.

Comment: The crucial point is to translate technical knowledge into business terms. You could start by simply measuring how much money your company is spending on manual actions, including customer crit sits coming out of deficient development processes. Some (the more stupid ones) managers only understand numbers - if so: give them numbers that support a sound position on such tooling. You know, in the end, **you** are the engineer; it is **your** responsibility to stand up to management and at least make it very clear how 1990ish your current setup is.

Comment: Accepted answer since I think it will be the only one I will get from the majority of reasonable and professional programmers. 
Only good thing is that the new projects (where I'm not contributing code) coming out are starting with more modern concepts (a building system with maven at least) since it's easier when you write from zero and don't have the product already in production. Still, no tools like Jenkins or similar for CI. And monitoring too..another Achille's heel.